# How to use remove(at:) in the app with CoreData?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

the problem I have is regarding the remove(at:) method which I want to use to be able to remove cards from the view after the user toggled the button. However, the issue I'm facing is that the array cardsArray is get only property meaning I cannot use remove(at:), so what are the alternatives to this?

Here's where I display all the cards in the particular "set of cards" (I'm using CoreData with one-to-many relationships):

```
struct FlashcardSetView: View {
    
    var set: FlashSets
    @ObservedObject var dataController = DataController.shared
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State private var showTermDefinitionView = false
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var isTapped = false
    @State private var isEdited = false
    @State private var selectedCards: [FlashCardData] = [] // Keep track of selected cards
    @State private var currentlySelectedCard: FlashCardData?
    @State var isLearned = false //1
    @State var isThink = false  //2
    @State var isHard = false   // 3
    @State var isRepeat = false // 4
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(set.cardsArray, id: \.self) { card in
                    //                    if let unwrappedCard = card {
                    //                        //Text(unwrappedCard.name)
                    //                    }
                            VStack {
                                Text(set.cardsArray.count.description)
                                SingleFlashCard(card: card,
                                                removal: {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        removeCard(card)
                                    }
                                    print("Removing card with animation")
                                }, isLearned: $isLearned,
                                                isThink: $isThink,
                                                isHard: $isHard,
                                                isRepeat: $isRepeat)
                                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                            }
                            .onAppear {
                                currentlySelectedCard = card
                            }
                }
   }
  }
}
```

Here's the SingleFlashCard view:

```
struct SingleFlashCard: View {
    let card: FlashCardData
    var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
    @State private var isTapped = false
    @State var term = ""
    @State var definition = ""
    @Binding var isLearned: Bool
    @Binding var isThink: Bool
    @Binding var isHard: Bool
    @Binding var isRepeat: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.white)
            //.offset(x: isLearned ? 500 : 0)
            //.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(getColor(), lineWidth: 2))// Here we change the border color based on the swipe direction
                .shadow(radius: 3)
            
            VStack {
                NavigationStack {
                    
                    Text(card.term ?? "Unnamed Card")
                        .offset(y: -100)
                    Divider()
                    if isTapped {
                        Text(card.definition ?? "Unnamed Card")
                            .offset(y: 100)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}
```

[FlashCardData entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCzph.png)
[FlashSets entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYyeI.png)

What possible corrections I may do in order for the program to work as expected?
Thank you.

Comment: So `cardsArray` is a computed property? Why not use the Set property `cards` instead and remove from it? You should even have a method `removeFromCards` (generated from your Core Data model) that you can use.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not providing the code for it. It is in the auto-generated file for the FlashSets: `var cardsArray: [FlashCardData] {
            let cardsArray = cards?.allObjects as? [FlashCardData] ?? []
            return cardsArray
        }`. I created it so that it would be of type [FlashCardData]

Comment: You don’t, the only way to actually affect the store is by going via the context. Any direct array modifications will only be cosmetic.

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: thank you for response, so you say I can directly remove form the 'cards' by doing `set.cards`?

Comment: yes or something like `set.removeFromCards(card)`

Comment: This makes sense, however, would I be able to then access this deleted data after for ex. all cards have been tapped and removed? The purpose for the delete method is to remove the cards from the "set", however, as you may see I have different buttons in there which would all represent the user's choice (hard to learn, easy ...). So, after all cards have been sort of "studied", the user would have an option to continue studying for cards he tapped as "hard".

Comment: Instead of “delete” you should create “archive” or “hide” you can do this in many different ways such as flipping a property.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, what way would you suggest to be the most efficient way for my case?

Comment: Just use  Bool, and use that Bool in your predicate so “hidden” cards don’t show up